# Order x-axis categorical variable using another categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis, phyloseq

I have a dataframe like follows:

```
Class       ID   Stage   Abundance          Substrat
OTUA      rep1  A-X1    123                  G
OTUA      rep2  A-X1    234                  PC
OTUA      rep3  A-X1    [numerical values]   [only two categorical values]
OTUB      rep1  A-X1
OTUA      rep1  EGG
OTUA      rep2  EGG
OTUA      rep1  EL
...       ...   ...    ...
```

I want to plot in geom_bar the ID of each sample by its stacked abundance for each different variable in the Class.

```
graph <- ggplot(data, aes(x=ID, y=Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  facet_grid(~substrat, scales="free_x") +
  geom_bar(aes(color=Class, fill=Class), stat="identity", position="stack")
```

I get something like this:

[image]

this works well, but I want to order the x axis data (ID) by the stage variable, with the specific order : "A-X0", "EGG", "EL", "LL","PP","P","A-X1", but I do not want to have the stage as label, I want to still have the ID as labels.

I have tried:

```
graph$stage <- as.character(graph$stage)
graph$stage <- factor(x = graph$stage, levels = c("A-X0", "EGG", "EL", "LL","PP","P","A-X1"))
```

and:

```
test <- ggplot(data_ps.sam.env.rel, aes(x=reorder(ID, stage), y=Abundance, fill=Class)) +
  facet_grid(~substrat, scales="free_x") +
  geom_bar(aes(color=Class, fill=Class), stat="identity", position="stack")
```

but i still get the samples in a random order, instead I expect that all the ID with "J8" would be together, all those with "J21" together, etc

Answer (score 0):

It could have been greate to have an example of your data using dput.
What do you think about adding a new variable using paste0(d$stage, d$ID) using this new variable in ggplot, and then removing the d$stage in the label using regex?

Comment: Thanks for you answer; I'm not familiar with regex, but since I have over 250 samples, I was trying to find a single step that would not necessitate coming back and manually changing the labels

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue if anyone is interested,
after doing the graph, I specified the order of the factors:

```
graph$data$ID <- as.character(ps.1.sample_class$data$ID)
graph$data$ID <- factor(x = graph$data$ID, 
                        levels = unique(graph$data$ID[order(as.character(graph$data$stage))]))
```